# crayon in R Markdown / knitr reports

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

How do I tell R Markdown / knitr to respect [crayon color codes](https://github.com/r-lib/crayon)? I have the following R Markdown report.

````
---
title: "MWE"
author: "Will Landau"
date: "11/20/2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r color}
message(crayon::make_style("green")("My green message."))
```
````

When I knit and render it, I see the output

```
## My green message.
```

but the text color is not green.

## **EDIT**

Use case: https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/issues/164

Comment: see [here](https://github.com/r-lib/crayon/issues/24) ... perhaps this will help you

Comment: Do you know if the hook was ever shipped with a package? I cannot view Gabor's gist.

Comment: I did not found such a function in the GitHub repository and also can not open his gist file ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [fansi](https://github.com/brodieG/fansi) is now on CRAN, I will add a solution that uses it:

````
---
title: "fansi Rmd"
output: html_document
---

```{r color, echo = FALSE}
options(crayon.enabled = TRUE)
knitr::knit_hooks$set(message = function(x, options){
  paste0(
    "<pre class=\"r-output\"><code>",
    fansi::sgr_to_html(x = x, warn = FALSE),
    "</code></pre>"
  )
})
message(crayon::make_style("green")("My green message."))
```
````

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

````
---
title: "MWE"
output: html_document
---

```{r color, echo = FALSE}
options(crayon.enabled = TRUE)
knitr::knit_hooks$set(message = function(x, options){
  paste0(
    "<pre class=\"r-output\"><code>",
    ansistrings::ansi_to_html(text = x, fullpage = FALSE),
    "</code></pre>"
  )
})
message(crayon::make_style("green")("My green message."))
```
````

Markdown output:

```
---
title: "MWE"
output: html_document
---

<pre class="r-output"><code>
## <span style="color:#4e9a06">My green message.</span>
</code></pre>
```

One caveat: [ansistrings](https://github.com/r-lib/ansistrings) is not released yet.

Comment: Does not work for me. I get ```! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'.``` Crayon 1.3.4, rmarkdown 1.8, knitr 1.20, R 3.4.3 (2017-11-30), Mint 18.2.

Comment: I had to add `term.cap = "256"` and replace < and > with "&lt;" and "&gt;" for it to work for me.